# Sum and bubble sort about funtion

Tags: c

I am a beginner in C language.

I studied all night and did my assignment.

But I wonder if there is a more efficient way.

The original structure is this.

```
typedef struct student {
    int id;
    int prob_1;
    int prob_2;
    int prob_3;
    int total_score;
    char grade;
}Student
```

I used typedef to change it to Student.

And I'll show you the contents of the function.

```
void cal_total_score(Student* s) {
    /*
    Problem (A):
    Implement the function "cal_total_score".
    - In each student, total_score must be the sum of prob_1, prob_2, and prob_3.
    - The codes outside the function must not be changed.
    */
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUMSTUDENT; i++) {
        s[i].total_score = s[i].prob_1 + s[i].prob_2 + s[i].prob_3;
    }
}

void student_bb_sort(Student* s) {
    /*
    Problem (B):
    Implement the function "student_bb_sort".
    - The student array "s" must be sorted according to total_score.
    - Bubble sort algorithm should be used for the sorting.
    - The codes outside the function must not be changed.
    */
    Student tmp;
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < NUMSTUDENT - 1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < NUMSTUDENT - 1 - i; j++) {
            if (s[j].total_score > s[j + 1].total_score) {
                tmp = s[j];
                s[j] = s[j + 1];
                s[j + 1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'll omit the main function for a length.

Please let me know if there are any more wrong or dangerous phrases or efficient ways.

Thank you.

============================================================================

This is a given main function in advance, so please read it if you need it.

```
typedef struct student {
    int id;
    int prob_1;
    int prob_2;
    int prob_3;
    int total_score;
    char grade;
}Student;

void cal_total_score(Student* s);
void student_bb_sort(Student* s);

int main() {
    Student s[NUMSTUDENT];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < NUMSTUDENT; i++) {
        s[i].id = i;
        s[i].prob_1 = rand() % 30 + 1;
        s[i].prob_2 = rand() % 30 + 1;
        s[i].prob_3 = rand() % 40 + 1;
        printf("Student %d\nP1: %d\tP2: %d\tP3: %d\n", s[i].id, s[i].prob_1, s[i].prob_2, s[i].prob_3);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < NUMSTUDENT; i++) {
        cal_total_score(&s[i]);
        printf("Student %d\tScore: %d\n", s[i].id, s[i].total_score);
    }

    student_bb_sort(s);
    printf("\nAfter Bubble Sort\n");

    for (i = 0; i < NUMSTUDENT; i++) {
        if ((float)i < (float)NUMSTUDENT / 3) {
            s[i].grade = 'C';
        }
        else if ((float)i < (float)NUMSTUDENT / 3 * 2 && (float)i >= (float)NUMSTUDENT / 3) {
            s[i].grade = 'B';
        }
        else {
            s[i].grade = 'A';
        }
        printf("Student %d\tScore: %d\tGrade: %c\n", s[i].id, s[i].total_score, s[i].grade);
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps this question is better asked at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "I'll omit the main function for a length." as long as you still provide a [mre].... No wait, MRe requires a `main()`.

Comment: More efficient in which way? Speed? Space? Teacher happiness?

Comment: @Yunnosch So I wrote down the entire main function below.

Comment: @Yunnosch it means for my score :)

Comment: The "entire" might mean that you did not get the point of a [mre].

Comment: Total score isn't bad, but bubble sort is one of the slowest sorts (as the number of items increases). Simply use `qsort()` to sort your array of struct. Search "qsort array of struct" on this site for help.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That however might plummit the teacher happiness if using bubble sort or self-implementing, or both, is required.

Comment: That's why I wrote down the main function below for reference. The question is above ====.

Comment: @David C. Rankin
I know bubble sort is inefficient, but the problem is to use bubble sort.

Comment: In that case -- use the bubble sort! `:)` Time difference is negligible until you get a few thousand elements anyway. (there will be a difference, it just won't matter that much)

Comment: @David C. Rankin There's nothing weird about the function, is there?

Comment: No, looks like a standard bubble-sort algorithm. There are several flavors, but the one you are using is pretty much the intro-standard bubble-sort. You have done a good job getting the code working, now you are in the profile/tweak phase. So long as you are using bubble-sort, then there isn't much else you can do. I'm not wild about your `if - else if ...` grade assignment and the cast of the loop variable `i` to `float`,  and don't follow the `(float)i < (float)NUMSTUDENT / 3`. I would expects a grade based on the total score for the student (or similar).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Oh, thank you. But I don't know why about that part because the professor wrote it down.

Comment: You can let him know that left 2 of us scratching our heads. It's the "why is he doing it that way?" that is the question. It's obvious he is just trying to get a distribution of `'C'`s, `'B'`s, and `'A'`s -- but that is one whacky way of doing it....

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I think so :(

Answer (score 1):

Consider what happens with arrays like 0,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11.
There is potential speed to be harvested for cases like that if you only do
`tmp = s[j];` only once before a loop with `s[j] = s[j + 1];` and then once `s[j + 1] = tmp;` after the loop. You are copying non-minimal `struct`s after all, not atomic pointers to structs.
That would also make the thing which is the moving "bubble" more obvious. If you name it `bubble` instead of `tmp` you might get an additional teacher smile on top.